# what Error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-intent

when I use recycler adapter then no Error will be Displayed but when I use recyleroption then error display when I searched then result will display fragment uses .

```
//code
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull Itemmodel itemmodel) {
    String quantity=itemmodel.getPquantityet();
    String id=itemmodel.getProductid();
    String priceavailable=itemmodel.getPriceavailable();
    holder.titletv.setText(itemmodel.getProductname());
    holder.descriptiontv.setText(itemmodel.getPdescription());
    holder.quantitytv.setText(quantity);
    holder.pricetv.setText(itemmodel.getPprice());
   /*        if(priceavailable.equals("true"))
       {
       holder.pricetv.setText(modelitem.getPprice());
      }else {
     holder.pricetv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }*/
    if(Integer.parseInt(quantity)<=5){
        holder.dangerpic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        holder.dangerpic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // Error is on Intent
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,BilActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",id);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `context` is null. No idea why (perhaps you made a mistake during the refactor) but maybe try this to test if it works?

```
Intent intent=new Intent(holder.itemView.context,BilActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id",id);
holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent); //You might have to cast this to an activity.
```

Comment: thanku sir I replaced context with get context() it work